# A* search algorithm: open set and heap

Tags: python, algorithm, heap, a-star

I'm working on an A* search algorithm implemention and this is what I came up with for the open list:

```
from heapq import heappush, heappop

class OpenList(set):
    '''
    This uses a heap for fast retrieval of the node with the lowest path score.
    It also uses a set for efficiently checking if a node is contained. 
    '''

    REMOVED = object()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        set.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self._heap = []

    def add(self, node):
        set.add(self, node)

        heappush(self._heap, (node.get_path_score(), node))

    def remove(self, node):
        set.remove(self, node)

        i = self._heap.index((node.get_path_score(), node))
        self._heap[i] = self.REMOVED

    def pop_node_with_lowest_path_score(self):
        ''' remove and return the node with the lowest path score '''

        item = heappop(self._heap)
        while item is self.REMOVED:
            item = heappop(self._heap)
        set.remove(self, item[1])
        return item[1]
```

Should I keep the path_score in the heap, when I mark the item as removed as in the following code:

```
self._heap[i] = (node.get_path_score(), self.REMOVED)
```

What do you think about it? What can be made more efficient, simple or cleaner?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### 1. Bug

1. You don't properly synchronize the set and the heap in all cases. For example, when taking a union:

   ```
   >>> a = OpenList()
   >>> a |= set([1,2,3])
   >>> a
   OpenList([1, 2, 3])
   >>> a._heap
   []
   ```

   If you insist on your class being a subclass of `set`, then you probably ought to intercept *every* method that modifies the set (and there are quite a few: `__isub__`, `__ior__`, `__ixor__`, `__iand__`, `discard`, `difference_update`, `intersection_update`, `symmetric_difference_update`, `update`, and `clear`, not to mention `copy`) and ensure that the heap is modified in a corresponding fashion.

   But this would be overkill for what ought to be a fairly simple class. What I would do instead would be to inherit from `object` instead of `set`, and implement the set as an instance member `_set`, in the same way that you have `_heap` as an instance member. With this approach, you can ensure that operations on `_set` always have corresponding operations on `_heap` so that they cannot get out of sync.

#### 2. Other issues

1. Your class is not as general as it could be. In particular, it can only be used to store objects which have a `get_path_score` method. Why not allow the user to pass in a `key` function that gets the score for an object? (As in [`sorted`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) and [`heapq.nlargest`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest) and similar functions.)
2. You call the superclass method directly via `set` rather than via the [`super()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super) function. This means that it's not possible for someone to create a new class that subclasses both your class and some other class `C`. (Because the method resolution order will go directly from your class to `set` instead of via the other class `C`.)
3. In the `remove` method, you replace the removed item with a placeholder. This takes time O(*n*) because you have to find the item in the heap. But removing the item from the heap and re-heapifying would also take O(*n*), and it would be simpler (because then there would be no need to handle the placeholder item in the `pop` method). So it's not clear to me that your approach is worth it.

   You should think about what you are trying to achieve: if you really want to have fast removal of items, then you need to be cleverer about how you find the removed item in the heap; but if you're happy for removal to be O(*n*), then you can simplify the code by just deleting the item from the heap and re-heapifying the remainder.

#### 3. Naming and documentation

1. The data structure used by the A* search algorithm is usually known as a [priority queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue): that is, a collection of items each of which is associated with a *priority* (or score), and which can be retrieved in order of their priority. So I think you could choose a better name than `OpenList` for your class.
2. Your docstring for the class is written with the wrong audience in mind. It contains *implementation details* ("uses a heap ... also uses a set") but this is not helpful for users of the class, who want to know *what it is for* and *how to use it*.
3. Your class is a good candidate for a [doctest](http://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html) or two.
4. The method name `pop_node_with_lowest_path_score` is absurd. Why not just `pop`?

#### 4. Rewrite

Here's how I'd rewrite the class to fix all the issues discussed above, assuming that you really do want fast removal of items. I'll let you reverse-engineer it to figure out how it works!

```
from heapq import heappush, heappop

class PriorityQueueElement(object):
    """
    A proxy for an element in a priority queue that remembers (and
    compares according to) its score.
    """
    def __init__(self, elem, score):
        self._elem = elem
        self._score = score
        self._removed = False

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self._score < other._score

class PriorityQueue(object):
    """
    A priority queue with O(log n) addition, O(1) membership test and
    amortized O(log n) removal.

    The `key` argument to the constructor specifies a function that
    returns the score for an element in the priority queue. (If not
    supplied, an element is its own score).

    The `add` and `remove` methods add and remove elements from the
    queue, and the `pop` method removes and returns the element with
    the lowest score.

    >>> q = PriorityQueue([3, 1, 4])
    >>> q.pop()
    1
    >>> q.add(2); q.pop()
    2
    >>> q.remove(3); q.pop()
    4
    >>> list(q)
    []
    >>> q = PriorityQueue('vext cwm fjord'.split(), key = lambda s:len(s))
    >>> q.pop()
    'cwm'
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._key = kwargs.pop('key', lambda x:x)
        self._heap = []
        self._dict = {}
        if args:
            for elem in args[0]:
                self.add(elem)

    def __contains__(self, elem):
        return elem in self._dict

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._dict)

    def add(self, elem):
        """
        Add an element to a priority queue.
        """
        e = PriorityQueueElement(elem, self._key(elem))
        self._dict[elem] = e
        heappush(self._heap, e)

    def remove(self, elem):
        """
        Remove an element from a priority queue.
        If the element is not a member, raise KeyError.
        """
        e = self._dict.pop(elem)
        e._removed = True

    def pop(self):
        """
        Remove and return the element with the smallest score from a
        priority queue.
        """
        while True:
            e = heappop(self._heap)
            if not e._removed:
                del self._dict[e._elem]
                return e._elem
```